# Flask/SQLAlchemy: Incompatible collection type: None is not list-like

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am confused. What's wrong?

I have two models, and a many to one relation.

I created form `Boss_add` for adding boss to database.
But, nothing works!

My models:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'users'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
  boss_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('boss.id'))
  boss = db.relationship('Boss', back_populates='users')

class Boss(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'boss'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  short_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
  users = db.relationship('User', back_populates='boss')
```

My Forms:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import IntegerField, StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, DateField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, DataRequired, Email, EqualTo
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField, QuerySelectMultipleField
from app.models import User, Boss

class Boss_add(FlaskForm):
  short_name = StringField('Short name', validators=[DataRequired()])
  users = QuerySelectMultipleField('Users', query_factory=lambda: db.session.query(User), get_pk=lambda a: a.id, get_label=lambda a: a.username, allow_blank=True)
  button = SubmitField('Add')
```

My view:

```
@app.route('/boss_add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def boss_add():
  form = Boss_add()
  if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    print("FIRST PRINT: ", type(form.users.data))   # DEBUG PRING 1
    print("SECOND PRINT: ", form.data)              # DEBUG PRING 2
    boss = Boss(short_name=form.short_name.data,
                users=form.users.data)
    db.session.add(boss)
    db.session.commit()
  return render_template('boss_edit.html', form=form)
```

My template:

```
<html><head><title>Boss add</title></head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<p>
            {{ form.short_name.label }}<br>
            {{ form.short_name }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.users.label }}<br>
            {{ form.users }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.button() }}</p>
</form>
</body></html>
```

**DEBUG PRINT:**

If I select user in list

```
FIRST PRINT: <class 'list'>
SECOND PRINT: {'short_name': '1111', 'users': [<User 1>], 'button': True, 'csrf_token': 'IjYxNDFhYzYyOGNlMGMzYTliNGYxOTA2NDYxYmE1ZDZkZmVjMjVkNDUi.DqPGxg.63Z-bKn8dgRGLNLxgMLUEzKMa15'}
```

If I not select user in list

```
FIRST PRINT: <class 'list'>
SECOND PRINT: {'short_name': '1111', 'users': [], 'button': True, 'csrf_token': 'IjYxNDFhYzYyOGNlMGMzYTliNGYxOTA2NDYxYmE1ZDZkZmVjMjVkNDUi.DqPGxg.63Z-bKn8dgRGLNLxgMLUEzKMa15'}
```

**TypeError: Incompatible collection type: None is not list-like**

How is this possible? Type: list, but in error: None.

If this important, my libs:

```
alembic          1.0.0  
Click            7.0    
Flask            1.0.2  
Flask-Login      0.4.1  
Flask-Migrate    2.2.1  
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2  
Flask-WTF        0.14.2 
itsdangerous     0.24   
jdcal            1.4    
Jinja2           2.10   
Mako             1.0.7  
MarkupSafe       1.0    
pip              18.1   
pkg-resources    0.0.0  
python-dateutil  2.7.3  
python-editor    1.0.3  
setuptools       40.4.3 
six              1.11.0 
SQLAlchemy       1.2.12 
Werkzeug         0.14.1 
wheel            0.32.1 
WTForms          2.2.1
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 261, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/src/app/routes.py", line 313, in client_add
    users=form.users.data)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 424, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 249, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 421, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 747, in _declarative_constructor
    setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 229, in __set__
    instance_dict(instance), value, None)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1042, in set
    given, wanted))
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: None is not list-like
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback, though the problem is likely `users=form.users.data`, where `form.users.data` happens to be `None`.

Comment: Somewhat related: [SqlAlchemy TypeError: Incompatible collection type: Line is not list-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265532/sqlalchemy-typeerror-incompatible-collection-type-line-is-not-list-like)

Comment: I'm add full traceback. Yep, on users=form.users.data

Comment: I guess it's `users=form.users.data`, is users `nullable` or not?

Comment: Your traceback hints that the error happens in another function `client_add`, not `boss_add`. If so, your debug prints are in the wrong place.

Comment: sorry client_add it is original name in project, for example in stackoverflow i'm rename client_add to boss_add.

Comment: Please don't do such changes, but use code that matches the traceback. You might accidentally even fix the error in the example code. For example while `allow_blank=True` on a `QuerySelectMultipleField` will result in an empty array, on a `QuerySetSelectField` it'll produce `None`, which you are obviously getting in the code that produced that traceback...

Comment: And also `QuerySelectField` will produce `None`, and you have an unused import for that where you define the form, which makes me believe that there is a chance that your broken code is actually using that.

Comment: @ilja-everilä how to be in `QuerySetSelectField` and `QuerySelectMultipleField` if want  possible to choose nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is you are trying to fill in `users` on `Boss` model on with `None` value

Try this in your `view`:

```
boss = Boss(short_name=form.short_name.data)
if form.users.data:
    for each in form.users.data: boss.users.append(each)
db.session.add(boss)
db.session.commit()
```

It should work pretty well

There is a chance that this one works too

```
boss = Boss(short_name=form.short_name.data, users=form.users.data if form.users.data else [])
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä How? Why?

Comment: Not!
Moreover, as can be seen from the model and form, the value can be empty and everything validates.
The error does not change, leave me blank or select user with username.
I have a lot of many to many in the project and there were no problems, and... here is the situation.

Comment: @XAOc Updated, check now

Comment: Do you know from which version the behavior has changed?
I have a project on Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.2)
And there such a trick is not required and everything works without it.

Comment: @XAOc I don't know, I always used them this way I dont use `WTForms` alot, Sry